# Why does UIAlertView not show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I have a code in a class method that must show a `UIAlertView` on successful operation (it's a Facebook SDK handler).
But, the alert doesn't show up.
Here's the code:

```
-(void) postCompletionHandler:(FBRequestConnection *)connection
                              result:(id)
                              result error:(NSError*)error
{
    if (!error) {
    // Link posted successfully to Facebook
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
    UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"FB Success!"
                                     message:result
                                     delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [successAlert show];


    }
 }
```

I put a breakpoint inside the block and

```
[successAlert show];
```

reaches execution and successfully executes. The debugger also shows, that this code excuted from the main, GUI thread.
I can't even imagine what can be the problem here.

Any ideas?

**Update**: big thanks for everyone who participated, your help means so much for me.
Now I solved the problem. The problem was, as pointed by @rmaddy, in incorrect parameter *result*, given to a constructor of an alertView class.
In the future I'll investigate on exception handling techniques in Xcode to prevent such an obvious errors to ruin my code.

Comment: Make delegate be self.

Comment: Your delegate is set to nil change to self and add `UIAlertViewDelegate` to the `@interface` line in your .h file

Comment: @WyattMufson That has no effect on whether it displays or not.

Comment: OP says that alert view isn't appearing, why would setting the delegate matter?  I'd rather suspect that this handler isn't running on main.

Comment: @danh The OP states it is running on the main thread.

Comment: @rmaddy - didn't see that.  As a diagnostic step, run that same code outside the completion handler, like before calling FB.  And I think executing on main in the block is a good thing to try too, in case OP is misreading the gdb.

Comment: I tried to set the delegate, but this doesn't yield me any good results.

Comment: Sanity check - is `result` really an `NSString`?

Comment: Sanity check #2 - Is `error` set to `nil`? Sanity check #3 - What else is going on in the app? Is the main thread stuck in a loop preventing the alert from being displayed?

Comment: @rmaddy, nope, it's an FBGraphObject

Comment: @rmaddy, I changed result to NSString and everything went ok. I'm feeling myself so dumb right now. Such an obvious error, and I had no idea how to fix it!

Comment: @JesusChrist I'm really surprised that passing in the wrong type of object didn't lead to some sort of crash.

Comment: @rmaddy, it lead, but it's hard to gain any info from objc_exception_throw.